# Entity Framework 5 Where() All() inside All() Query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am having difficulty executing the following linq query using Entity Framework 5.0.

```
entities.Table1.Where(a => 
    a.Table2.All(b => b.Table3.All(c => c.Field3 != null)))
```

The database structure is hierarchical with a 1 to 0..1 relationship for each inner table.
For example:

```
Table1    Table2     Table3
------    ------     ------
ID        ID         ID
Field1    Table1ID   Table2ID
          Field2     Field3
```

Upon execution I receive the following inner exception:

```
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

However the following code works fine.

```
entities.Table1.Where(a => 
    a.Table2.All(b => b.Field2 != null))
```

So I believe it is because entity cannot convert the second All() inside the first block.
Is there a possible way to work around this?

Comment: For what it's worth, I just tried this on my code with a similar x, y, z path and it worked fine.  (was unsurprisingly a bit slow)  I'm using EF6 with Sql Server.

Comment: The issue is that we will be moving to a 1 to many relationship for each inner table so I need to check all records in table 3 that are related to table 1 via table 2, match a certain condition. != null is just there for this example.

Comment: Just to update, I have upgraded to EF 6.0, we use MySQL and it still doesn't work so assume its a problem with MySQL support.

Comment: Interesting, yeah, it would actually surprise me more than unsurprise me for this to work with the mysql EF drivers.  I was using it for quite some time and there are *numerous* incompatibilities when compared again Sql Server.  (Not sure if this has been fixed now, but I couldn't even do `foo.Outer.Where(x => x.Inner.Any(y => y.Bar != null))`.